# Down Payment Requirement for a non-Permanent Resident of Canada

Tags: mortgage, canada, regulation

I am waiting for my PR under spousal sponsorship to come thru. My Canadian husband wants us to buy a condo in Port Alice and has pre qualified by adding my Social Security income in with his. Question is.... he can get 95% financing but says I have to have my PR before I go on mortgage with him otherwise it is 35% down payment instead of 5%.

What are the specific down-payment rules which would require this? Do we have to wait and risk losing out on a great condo while waiting for my PR to go thru, or does him being a Canadian set aside the fact I’m not a permanent resident yet?

Comment: Good question - I hope you don't mind my edits to add additional clarity and hopefully gain better attention on the site.

Answer (score 1):

The basis for my answer is the Government of Canada's main website, Canada.ca.

On anything that I can see referring to down-payment requirements, I can't find anywhere that restricts the amount on the basis of residency status. Instead, the requirement to have a down payment of between 5-20% is based on the value of the home itself [with homes <500k needing 5% down payment, between 500k-10M needing between 5-10% down payment, and >1M having a 20% down payment].

For example:

- https://www.canada.ca/en/financial-consumer-agency/services/mortgages/down-payment.html
- https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/new-immigrants/new-life-canada/housing/buying.html
- https://www.cmhc-schl.gc.ca/en/co/moloin/index.cfm

It seems from what I can see online that the requirement for a 35% down payment is based on common individual lender policies, rather than government regulation. Therefore, a discussion with your bank will likely be required to resolve this fully. It will be up to your bank as to whether they allow the lower down payment - keeping in mind that they would put a higher down payment in place if they believe you are a higher risk than a PR.

**With a PR spouse, it would seem to me that your risk in the bank's eyes should go down, and a bank should be willing to consider reducing the down payment requirement**. Nothing conclusive, but from some online searches it seems others have had success making that argument.

Good luck!